# What is the highest worth item to resell?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

I'm looking for the item that fetches the highest usual value (not counting "hot item" multiplier) in the Nook's Cranny general store. I.e., what sells higher than the expensive Nintendo Switch (worth 7,000 bells)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a crown sells for 250,000 bells and a royal crown sells for 300,000 bells

Answer (score 3):

[Coelacanth](https://animalcrossing.fandom.com/wiki/Coelacanth), [Great White Shark](https://animalcrossing.fandom.com/wiki/Shark), [Dorado](https://animalcrossing.fandom.com/wiki/Dorado) and [Stringfish](https://animalcrossing.fandom.com/wiki/Stringfish) sell for 15k bells each.

Comment: Worthy of a mention is the Gold Nugget, that sells for 10k a piece and can be found, on average, once per day.

Answer (score 3):

Found the **whirlpool bath**, which resells for **32,500 bells**:

[image: 32,500 bells]
[image: whirlpool bath]